# How do i fix this path error while creating a new react app?

Tags: reactjs, node.js

Im a very new user. I am trying to create a new React App. I installed node.js on windows 11 and ran the executable. Then i went to VSCode terminal/Cmd Prompt/Node js cmd prompt and typed `npx create-react-app` but i get this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\zheng\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\zheng\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I followed a youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3M9qKvFZeg&t=7s&ab_channel=CodeWithArjun
not sure where i went wrong.

Version:

```
node -v
v21.3.0
npm -v
10.2.4
```

Tried changing the path of installation from C:\Users\zheng to another location. same issue

Comment: Use `npx create-react-app app-name` instead of  `npx create-react-app`.  Makes sure you installed npx by  `npm install npx`

Comment: I did this and it worked.

```npm uninstall -g create-react-app```

```npm install -g create-react-app```

Now you can create a new react app by using
``` npx create-react-app app-name```